# Is there a canonical reason why Shin saved Noi when she was trying to become a devil?

Tags: dorohedoro

When Noi was trying to be a devil, she was banned from using magic for a year. One day when was having dinner with Shin, some assassins came in and blew a bomb on them. Shin being the white knight he was immediately shielded Noi from the blast which blew up his lower body. Noi used her magic to heal him which ruined her devil prospects.

This stuck out as particularly strange to me. Shin had already known Noi healed. If she got blown up, she would've healed anyway. She would've used her magic, sure, but when Shin tried to protect her and got almost killed, she still used magic. I just thought of Shin's attempt at whiteknighting as particularly boneheaded and pointless because he should've known, for the time they've been together, that Noi would save him. She would lose her devil ticket either way. This particular plot point feels contrived to me, like it was included merely for a heartfelt moment.

Has the author ever elaborated on why things went down that way? Perhaps in interviews or responses to fans' letters?

Comment: It's simply shin didn't think 'for the time they've been together, that Noi would save him.'